# Chart.js ignoring canvas height & width

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Following the [Chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart) 
I am trying to draw a small chart:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels:['15-2016','16-2016','17-2016',],
    datasets:[
      {
        label:'Yes',
        data:[3.4884,1.1628,1.3514,],
        backgroundColor:'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        borderColor:'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        pointRadius:0
      },
      {
        label:'Maybe',
        data:[0.5571,1.3298,0.791,],
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255,206,86,1)',
        borderColor:'rgba(255,206,86,1)',
        pointRadius:0
      },
      {
        label:'No',
        data:[0,0,0,],
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        borderColor:'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        pointRadius:0
      }
    ]
  }        
});
</script>
```

However, when the page is rendered the canvas somehow becomes

```
<canvas style="height: 929px; width: 929px;" id="myChart" width="1858" height="1858"></canvas>
```

which is waaaaay too big for my needs. How can I set the width and height of the canvas to be what I want?

Comment: if you can get to it, try to set a breakpoint in the core.helper.js file of chartjs and its getting its height from the canvasElementReference.parentNode so if css isnt controlling that, you could add rules for css to style its parent and let the canvasElementReference.parentNode.clientWidth and heights be based off of the css style. Thats the actual code logic if you can follow what i mean itll fix your issue for anyone else that cares

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to hardcode the size of the graph by turning off responsiveness:

```
options: {
  responsive: false
}
```

Comment: It works but not perfect, because i only want to fix height not width, if i only give height it reduces the width too.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by adding "maintainAspectRatio: false" to the options.

```
options : {
    maintainAspectRatio: false
};
```

Comment: My chart does not show up when applied this option.

Answer (score 1):

Using Both options, maintainAspectRatio: false AND responsive: false seem to do the trick of making the chart fit the canvas as sized in the canvas height and width tags.