# canvas does not display proper width and height chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I use canvas width and highth as follow

```
<canvas id="myChart" height="400" width="400" ></canvas>
```

However, when the page is rendered the canvas somehow becomes

```
<canvas height="1643" id="myChart" width="1643" style="display: block; width: 1643px; height: 1643px;"></canvas>
```

I found [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577892/chart-js-ignoring-canvas-height-width) and such solution works for me too,

```
options: {
  responsive: false
}
```

But I'm not sure that that is proper solution just to turn off responsive option becaouse that is one of the cool  thing in chart.js

my code

```
<Html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.js" ></script>
</head>

<Body>
    <canvas id="myChart" height="400" width="400" ></canvas>
</Body>
<script>
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Steps',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',

                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                },

                {
                label: "Goal Line",
                    type:'line',
                    data: [{x:0,y:10},{x:0,y:10},{x:0,y:10},{x:0,y:10},{x:0,y:10},{x:0,y:10}],
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    borderColor: "rgba(243, 52, 52,1)",
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',                                                

            }

                ]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        },         
                    }],
                         xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        },

                    }]
                },

            }
        });

</script>

</Html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css max-width and min-width if you want to avoid your chart from being too big or too small:

```
<canvas id="myChart" height="400" width="400" style="min-width: 200px; max-width: 600px"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: You don't need to set a width via css. You can place the  element within a grid column. Charts are responsive, so they will adjust the width to the size of the parent.

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
    <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
</div>
```